# activation a sub that is implemented in another worksheet

Tags: vba, call, office-2013

I want to `call` a sub in another worksheet. I tried this but as I persumed it didn't work:

```
Call ThisWorkbook.sheet("test").callingsub
```

Is it even possible to activate a sub that is in another worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed:

```
Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").callingsub
```